# Crear base de datos mysqli desde php

Tags: php, mysqli

Estoy intentando crear una base de datos desde php pero no lo consigo.

El servidor que uso es un debían 8 con plesk

y este es el código con el que lo estoy intentando:

```
    <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "DB_Admin";
$password = "$4Fd3rnke";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Create database
$sql = "CREATE DATABASE myDB";
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "Base de datos creada correctamente";
} else {
    echo "Error creando la base de datos: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

El error que me esta dando es este:

```
Error creando la base de datos: Access denied for user 'DB_Admin'@'localhost' to database 'myDB'
```

No se si el fallo lo tengo en el usuario o puede ser otra cosa. El usuario lo he creado con privilegios para crear bases de datos.

¿Que puedo tener mal?

El usuario en plesk lo tengo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el ultimo intento de dar privilegios a el usuario he puesto esto:

```
$sql = "CREATE DATABASE myDB GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON myDB.* To 'DB_Admin'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;";
```

Pero de momento me da error de sintaxis.

Comment: edita tu pregunta con lo que haz intentado

Comment: @cignius Editado. De momento tengo error de sintaxis que estoy intentando descubrir que tengo mal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al final resulta que plesk pasa olimpicamente de los permisos del usuario. 
He cambiado los permisos del usuario desde phpmyadmin y ya funciona con el código original.

Answer (score 1):

El mensaje de error dice que el usuario no tiene acceso a la base de datos, no que no tenga privilegios de crear bases de datos. Intenta darle privilegios al usuario una vez que crea la base de datos:

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON myDB.* To 'DB_Admin'@'localhost';`

Comment: Dice que lo mismo :_(

Comment: a eso yo le agregaría `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` para actualizar los privilegios

Comment: Igual @cignius dice lo mismo